# SYSTEM hive of the registry is causing computer to BSOD on boot

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, bsod

After some work on my computer, perhaps some updates installs, it didn't boot anymore. BSOD on windows logo loading. After some research I've found out that if I replace the SYSTEM hive of the registry with the last backup it boots ok, but of course goes back to an old stage of machine setup.

So my question is: where does registry stores hardware and/or updates/software that loads in the machine boot, so that I can check which program is producing that BSOD and disable it?

System is Win 7 64 bits SP1

Comment: Can you use a program like BlueScreenViewer to provide information on the BSOD that happen.  Be sure your system is setup so your system does not automatically restart without dumping the information required to determine the cause of the BSOD.  You likely will have to transfer the file to another computer.  In the end your hack is likely the cause of your problems and was likely the incorrect solution for the problem you originally faced.

Comment: @Ramhound I could use that program if it can access the dumps in another windows install, is that possible? because i'm unbootable to that unit, so I can boot in my other windows install and run it for that. can you give me some instructions?

Comment: You can indeed transfer the dumps.  There really isn't any instruction to give.

Comment: @Ramhound I've activated thru register all the options related to dumps, but it seems it's not generating anything. could it be because the bsod happens too soon in boot?

Comment: I assume Safe Mode is not an option?

Comment: No, safe mode produces the same error.